# Continuously draw rectangles on a canvas at the location of a mouse while the mouse is held down

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouse

I'm trying to make a drawing program using javascript and the HTML canvas, and I need to continuously draw a circle at the location of the mouse, and I'm not exactly sure how to do it. I have a rough idea but my code (not surprisingly) doesn't work. Any idea how I can make it work? the code is here.

```html
<canvas width = '450' height = '450' id = 'drawing'> </canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  var drawing = false
  function startmoving(){ drawing = true;}
  function stopmoving() { drawing = false;}

  function draw() {
    if (drawing == true){
      ctx.fillstyle = 'black';
      ctx.fillRect(event.clientX, event.clientY, 4, 4)
    }
    setInterval(drawing, 10);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You could set an interval to draw a circle until the mouse up event is fired, then clear the interval.

Comment: I suppose, I'll tell you if it works. I think there might also be an issue with the clientX and clientY tough. PS: I have a chat room that needs some members, and from looking at your profile you look like the kind of person that would be great to have there. This is the link if you're interested. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224372/ameteur-web-design-coders

Comment: event.clientX and event.clientY has to be under an event listener. There is no "event" variable because it's not wrapped in an event listener. Also, I misread your question. You want circles to draw when the program starts. I'll post an answer that should work.

Comment: Whoops. Well I am one hell of an idiot then.

Comment: Fixed it. Check my answer. If you need clarification just ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set a mousedown/mouseup and mousemove listener for the canvas, then make and place a rectangle at the coordinates if the mouse is down, and stop the drawing if the mouse is up. Also, clientX and clientY are for the top left visible part of the page. pageX and pageY are for the top left of the page. So if you scroll down with clientX and clientY, it will draw at the position of the current page, making it appear weird. A fix? Use pageX and pageY (replace clientX and clientY with pageX and pageY)!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas width='450' height='450' id='drawing'> </canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');
    var drawing = false;
    //start the drawing if the mouse is down
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      drawing = true;
    })
    //stop the drawing if the mouse is up
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      drawing = false;
    });
    //add an event listener to the canvas for when the user moves the mouse over it and the mouse is down
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      //if the drawing mode is true (if the mouse button is down)
      if (drawing == true) {
        //make a black rectangle
        ctx.fillstyle = 'black';
        //put the rectangle on the canvas at the coordinates of the mouse
        ctx.fillRect(event.clientX, event.clientY, 4, 4)
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I only want to do this while the mouse is both down and over the canvas.

Comment: I think i can figure it out myself, but update away. Thank you!

Comment: gonna join that chat room you seem really nice